# adopting RandomAccessCollection protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

```
public class Container2: RandomAccessCollection
{
    public typealias Indices = DefaultIndices<Container2>

    public typealias Index = Int
    //typealias SubSequence = Container2
    public var arr:[Int] = [1,2,3,4,5]
    
    public var endIndex: Index {
        return 5
    }
    
    public var startIndex:Index{
        return 0
    }
    
    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int{
        return i+1
    }
    
    public subscript(position: Int) -> Int{
        get{
            return arr[position]
        }
        set{
            arr[position] = newValue
        }
    }
    
    /*func index(before i: Int) -> Int{
        return i-1
    }*/
    
     public subscript(bounds: Range<Int>) -> Container2{
        get{
            return Container2()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to adopt the RandomAccessCollection protocol from a class. I deliberately leave out the `func index(before:)` function because there is already a default implementation of that function in RandomAccessCollection. I do understand that that function's implementation is required because of BiDirectionalCollection from which RandomAccessCollection inherits. My question is why would the compiler complain that func index(before:) implementation is required when there is already a default implementation in RandomAccessCollection that i can use? Thanks.

Comment: Also posted on swift-users: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20170306/004956.html.

Comment: The index type for the code is just Int which is derived from Strideable. The code should be able to use the the default implementation. Thanks

Comment: @DonGiovanni I didn't mention it at the time, but you also need to have an `Indices` type of `CountableRange<Index>` to get the default indexing implementation (you can see [the extension here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/RandomAccessCollection.swift#L200)).

Answer (score 1):

> why would the compiler complain that func index(before:) implementation is required when there is already a default implementation in RandomAccessCollection that i can use?

I had a similar problem as you and wondered the same. In the comments, Hamish answers our question, but I want to give more detail.

Read the main code comments to `RandomAccessCollection`.

```
/// The `RandomAccessCollection` protocol adds further constraints on the
/// associated `Indices` and `SubSequence` types, but otherwise imposes no
/// additional requirements over the `BidirectionalCollection` protocol.
/// However, in order to meet the complexity guarantees of a random-access
/// collection, either the index for your custom type must conform to the
/// `Strideable` protocol
```

You defined `Indices` as `DefaultIndices<Container2>`. This conflicts with `typealias Index = Int` because `Int` is a different type than `Container2`. The `Indices` element type has to be a collection of the `Index` type.

Another problem is that `Container2` does not conform to `Strideable` like the code comment says. Because your index type of `Container2` does not conform to `Strideable` then the protocol extensions for `index(before:)` on `RandomAccessCollection` cannot be used. Thus, the complier complains.

I copied your code into a playground, and made the complier error go away by changing 1 line:

```
    public typealias Indices = Range<Int>
```

Also, `subscript(position:)` makes sense but `subscript(bounds:)` is wrong. You have `Container2` coded to return `Int` not copies of itself. You can delete that func because it is not needed.

The reason I hit a similar problem as you was because I tried to implement a type that conformed to `RandomAccessCollection` by using the errors that the Xcode code completion gave me. This is folly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64142584/conform-a-custom-type-to-randomaccesscollection-with-only-a-subscript) has a minimal conformance example. However, I pared that down to something even smaller.

```
struct SomeInts : RandomAccessCollection {
    var startIndex: Int { 0 }
    var endIndex: Int  { 5 }
    subscript(position: Int) -> Int {
        get { [51, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71][position] }
    }
}
```

The lesson from this is: ignore Xcode code completion telling you to define those generic type aliases as concrete types. Instead, implement the minimum functions using concrete types, and let type inference tell the complier what those generic type aliases should be.