# Conform a custom type to RandomAccessCollection with only a subscript

Tags: arrays, swift, protocols

I usually implement types that behave like arrays, like this one:

```swift
struct Dataset: RandomAccessCollection {
    let ids: [Int]
    // Other properties and methods...

    // Boilerplate
    var startIndex: Int { ids.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Int { ids.endIndex }
    func formIndex(after i: inout Int) { i += 1 }
    func formIndex(before i: inout Int) { i -= 1 }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        // Dummy example, could be more complex and return a different type
        return ids[index]
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to write each time lot of boilerplate code for the `RandomAccessCollection` conformance. I'd like a protocol or a mechanism reduce the boilerplate to just one or two requirements:

- An underlying `RandomAccessCollection` (like the `ids` property in my example) from which to infer the protocol requirements (`startIndex`, `endIndex`, `formIndex`)
- A subscript that would complete the remaining requirement

This mechanism would resemble the way Dataset inheritance is done in Pytorch currently: only with a `__len__` and `__getitem__` requirements.

I come up with a draft like this:

```swift
protocol ArrayProtocol: RandomAccessCollection where Index == BaseCollection.Index {
    associatedtype BaseCollection: RandomAccessCollection
    
    var baseCollection: BaseCollection { get set }
    subscript(index: Index) -> Element { get set }
}

// Provide the default implementation of the RandomAccessCollection protocol
extension ArrayProtocol {
    var startIndex: Index { baseCollection.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { baseCollection.endIndex }
    func formIndex(after i: inout Index) { baseCollection.index(after: i) }
    func formIndex(before i: inout Index) { baseCollection.index(before: i) }
}
```

This protocol would be used like that:

```swift
struct Dataset: ArrayProtocol {
    let ids: [Int]
    // Other properties and methods...

    // No more boilerplate
    var baseCollection: [Int] { ids }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        // Dummy example, could be more complex and return a different type
        return ids[index]
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way to make it working and I feel like the associated type is not a very good design pattern.

Any idea to solve this?

EDIT: the `where Index == BaseCollection.Index` clause is not necessary, the subscript could have a different `Index` type than the underlying collection.

Comment: This seems to work properly though typealias `BaseCollection = [Int]` is not required. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associated types are generally used for the generic type (usually the element of the collection). Add the associated type to it `typealias BaseCollection = [Int]` and remove the subscript requirement for set.

```
protocol ArrayProtocol: RandomAccessCollection where Index == BaseCollection.Index {
    associatedtype BaseCollection: RandomAccessCollection
    var baseCollection: BaseCollection { get set }
    subscript(index: Index) -> Element { get }
}
```

---

```
extension ArrayProtocol {
    var startIndex: Index { baseCollection.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { baseCollection.endIndex }
    func formIndex(after i: inout Index) { baseCollection.index(after: i) }
    func formIndex(before i: inout Index) { baseCollection.index(before: i) }
}
```

---

```
struct Dataset: ArrayProtocol {
    typealias BaseCollection = [Int]
    var baseCollection: BaseCollection = [ ]
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int { baseCollection[index] }
}
```

---

---

Note that if you would like to keep the set requirement `subscript(index: Index) -> Element { get set }` you would need also to make sure `BaseCollection` conforms to `MutableCollection` as well.

```
subscript(index: Int) -> BaseCollection.Element {
    get { baseCollection[index] }
    set { baseCollection[index] = newValue } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in the above answer.

```
func formIndex(after i: inout Index) { baseCollection.index(after: i) }
func formIndex(before i: inout Index) { baseCollection.index(before: i) }
```

should be

```
func formIndex(after i: inout Index) { baseCollection.formIndex(after: &i) }
func formIndex(before i: inout Index) { baseCollection.formIndex(before: &i) }
```